# Как получить доступ к папке, которая находится ваше по уровню в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Сайт имеет папку `backend` и `frontend`, которые имеют свои контроллеры, модели, виды. Внутри папки `frontend` есть модуль CRM, внутри которого тоже есть контроллеры, модели виды.

Мне надо, чтобы модуль CRM использовал `layout` и `view` из папки `frontend`, а не свой собственный.

В файле `module.php` я прописал:

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{

public $layoutPath = '@app/views/layouts';
public $layout = 'main';
...
}
```

на что получаю ошибку:

> yii\base\ViewNotFoundException: The view file does not exist: D:\OSPanel\domains\Etest.com\frontend\modules\crm\views\layouts\main.php

Танцы с бубном вокруг `$layoutPath` и `$layout`, которые заключались в прописывании относительных, абсолютных урлов, псевдонимов не дают эффекта. Я получаю ту же ошибку. При этом `$layoutPath` не особо влияет на ситуацию.

то, что я понял из ошибок - это то, что самым верхним уровнем для модуля CRM является папка `modules` и он не может смотреть в папку `fronend/views/latout`

Вопрос: как моему модулю получить доступ к общему шаблону?

Comment: Если в рендере использовать два слэша, тогда вьюшка будет грузиться из `frontend/views`, вполне возможно и с шаблонами так работает. <?=$this->render('//blocks/_button')?> В данном случае используется `frontend/views/blocks/_button`

Comment: Да, эта штука помогает! Два слеша дают возможность посмотреть выше

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
public $layout = '@frontend/views/layouts/main';
```

Comment: нет, оно смотрит в папки под папкой D:\OSPanel\domains\Etest.com\frontend\modules\